# Building html elements with Razor and Javascript, in MVC

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc, razor, escaping

Using MVC:

While looping through my `Model` with `Razor` in a `Javascript` function I can't build my `Javascript` variable. I have tryed escaping some `Razor`lines with `@:` but I still do something wrong that I can't figure out.

What is the right way to combine `Razor` and `Javascript` in examples like this?

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var elements = [];
    var tableElement = ""; // Resharper: Local variable 'tableElement' is never used.

    @foreach (var w in Model)
    {
        @: tableElement += "<table>" +
                    @: tableElement += "<thead>" + // This "+=" and the others "+=" below gives "Syntax error"
                @: tableElement += "<tr>" +
                    @: tableElement += "<th>Number</th>" +
                    @: tableElement += "<th>Description</th>" +
                @: tableElement += "</tr>" +
            @: tableElement += "</thead>" +
        @: tableElement +=  "</table>" +

        foreach (var e in w.Exercices)
        {
            @: tableElement +=  "<tr>" +
                @: tableElement +=  "<th>@e.Number</th>" +
                @: tableElement +=  "<th>@e.Stk</th>" +
                @: tableElement +=  "<th>@e.Name</th>" +
                @: tableElement +=  "<th>@e.Description</th>" +
            @: tableElement +=  "</tr>"; // <-- end with ";"?
        }

        @: elements.push(tableElement);
    }

    fillTableProgram(elements);
});

function fillTableProgram(elements) {
    var elementIndex = 0;
    var tbody = "";
    for (var i = 0; elementIndex < elements.length; elementIndex++) {
        tbody += '<tr>';
        for (var j = 0; j < 7 && elementIndex < elements.length; elementIndex++, j++) {
            tbody += '<td>';
            tbody += elements[elementIndex];
            tbody += '</td>';
        }
        tbody += '</tr>';
    }

    $('#tableProgram').empty();
    $('#tableProgram').append(tbody);
}
```

Sidenote:

I can render the html elements, outside `<script>` `</script>`, but I would prefer to have the control the `JavaScript` function `fillTableProgram` gives me.

```
@foreach (var w in Model)
{
    @: <table style="background-color: lightblue; border-style: outset;">
        <thead style="background-color: darkcyan;">
            <tr>
                <th>Number</th>
                <th>Stk</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Description</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        foreach (var e in w.Exercices)
        {
            <tr>
                <th>@e.Number</th>
                <th>@e.Stk</th>
                <th>@e.Name</th>
                <th>@e.Description</th>
            </tr>
        }
    @: </table>
    <br/>
}
```

EDIT**************:

I can use `<text>` to escape `Razor` instead of `@:` on every line. Also I can see that I should't use `@tableElement +=` on every line because im concanating instead of assigning every line. I still don't get the exercises printet, but that's maybe a Model problem Serverside.

Is the use `<text>` still the best way to handle this case?

```
    @foreach (var w in Model)
    {
        <text>
            tableElement += "<table>" +
                                "<thead>" +
                                    "<tr>" +
                                        "<th>Number</th>" +
                                        "<th>Description</th>" +
                                    "</tr>" +
                                "</thead>" +
                            "</table>";

            @foreach (var e in w.Exercices)
            {
                <text>
                    console.log('e:' + "@( e )" );
                    tableElement +=  "<tr>" +
                                        "<th>  @(e.Number)  </th>" +
                                        "<th>  @e.Stk  </th>" +
                                        "<th>  @e.Name  </th>" +
                                        "<th>  @e.Description  </th>" +
                                    "</tr>";

                </text>
            }

        </text>

        @: elements.push(tableElement);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution:
Using `<text>` and concanate the right way was what I needed.

$(document).ready(function () {
        var elements = [];
        var tableElement = "";

```
    @foreach (var w in Model)
    {
        <text>
            tableElement = "";

            tableElement += "<table>" +
                                "<thead>" +
                                    "<tr>" +
                                        "<th>Number</th>" +
                                        "<th>Description</th>" +
                                    "</tr>" +
                                "</thead>";

            @foreach (var e in w.Exercices)
            {
                <text>
                    tableElement += "<tr>" +
                        "<th>@e.Number</th>" +
                        "<th>@e.Stk</th>" +
                        "<th>@e.Name</th>" +
                        "<th>@e.Description</th>" +
                    "</tr>";
                </text>
            }

        tableElement += "</table>";

        elements.push(tableElement);
        </text>
    }

    fillTableProgram(elements);
});
```